# Rounded corners for top container regardless of the colors of the background of children views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that that has different colors for different Textview

```
  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizonetal">

    <Textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAA"
        android:background="drawable/RED" />

    <Textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BBB"
        android:background="drawable/BLUE" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizonetal">

    <Textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CCC"
        android:background="drawable/ORANGE" />

    <Textview
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DDD"
        android:background="drawable/GREEN" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make the whole layout a rounded corner?
IF I create a rounded corner bg then I have to create a rounded corner with fill color for every text view. But I was wonder if I can take the full layout and make its corners rounded (sort of clip the rectangle corners).

This is needed because this layout is set as a dialog and I want the dialog to be of rounded corners

Thank you

Here is a picture of what I mean . I have this rectangular view/layout which has different colors. Imagine there is a brown background due to another layout behind it. How can I make the ractangular view rounded (and transparent corners) like in the second image

[image]

Comment: can you show us what is your end result looks like? sample image or drawing. I don't really understand your question if you want your whole layout to be rounded, it's easy

Comment: @SopheakSok I added image to explain more

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to use cardview as a root layout and set the corner and that will override all the children bounds